# The use of the word "of" between nouns and other prepositions

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can all composite nouns be converted using the word "of".
For example: A B C D becomes D of C of B of A
Supermarket credit card system = System of card of credit of supermarket.
Credit card (A B) = Card of credit (B of A)

I have checked the first example on Grammarly demo and it points to an error.

Is it valid what I did?

Also, look the example below:

"The elephant above the sky above the cross above the lands is big".

In that case, the article "the" has to be behind the nouns so that the sentence with the preposition "above" behind the nouns make sense. Why it is not the case of "supermarket credit card system"? Also, if the example I gave at is first is correct, why is it valid to write "System of card of credit of supermarket" without the article "the" preceding the nouns?

Thanks.

Comment: Curiosity: In Portuguese language, "of" means "de" and "of the" is "da" in case the noun is female and "do" in case the noun is male.

Comment: Example: "Card of credit" -> "Cartão de crédito". "Card of the bank" -> Cartão do banco. "Card of the woman" -> Cartão da mulher.

Comment: Unlike Portuguese (and Spanish), English doesn't like having many _of_'s in a row; more than two is unusual, and more than three is odd. Some (many) compound nouns can be converted with _of_, but many others can't.

Comment: But is it grammatically valid ? Another example: Milk of cow of farm of whey of cheese of Sweden. Means it can be a milk of a cow that lives in a farm in Sweden that fabricates whey that comes from cheese.

Comment: @XianLiu Your last example is not only not normal and far too complex to be good English the items in the list are in the wrong order to convey the meaning you ascribe to them. "Whey of milk of cow of cheese farm of Sweden" comes closer but even that is a long way from normal. The whole sentence reminds me of the traditional children's rhyme "This is the house that Jack built" which ends up in an accumulated sentence something like "This is the dog that chased the cat that killed the rat that ate the corn that lay in the house that Jack built". And that is deliberately complex.

Comment: But is it technically valid?

Comment: Despite what you may have been taught, there is no such thing as 'technically valid' when it comes to novel English sentences.

Comment: What do you mean? I made my question because I pretend to make an algorithm that verifies if a sentence in the present has a valid grammar structure.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but it's not idiomatic.

Comment: It also becomes confusing because it's difficult to tell how the phrases should be grouped. "A of B of C" could mean "(A of B) of C" or "A of (B of C)"

Comment: Whey doesn't 'come from cheese', it is part of milk, of which cheese is made. Any native speaker would find your example completely baffling.